# Browser-sync не сохраняет скролл при обновлении страницы

Tags: gulp, browsersync, gulp-watch

После правок Browser-Sync не сохраняет скролл (скроллит вверх, примерно в середину страницы).

При обновлении css выскакивает сообщение "Injected:style.css". Т.е. вроде страница целиком обновляться не должна.
Версия browsersync 2.18.13

UPD: Похоже проблема возникает только в Firefox. В хром проблема исчезает, но очень хотелось бы продолжать работать в Firefox, на него завязано очень много вещей в рабочем процессе.

```
const gulp         = require('gulp');
const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('server', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'build/',
    },
    open: false,
    online: false,

    files:[  
        'build/*.html',
        'build/css',
        'build/js',
        'build/fonts/',
        'build/img',
    ],

    ghostMode: {
        scroll: true
    },

    logLevel: 'info', // 'debug', 'info', 'silent', 'warn'
    logConnections: false,
    logPrefix: "Browser-Sync",
    port: 8080,
    notify: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Попробуй более точно указать путь стилей, скажем '/build/css/**/*.css'

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но увы - это проблему не решило.